# Moving Items from a List to Another List with both being in an Array of Lists

Tags: c#

I have two arrays of lists. Both have a random number of lists and each one of the lists has 60 random numbers in it.

What i want to do is move half of the items in one list to another list. However both lists are in there own array of lists. I've tried looking up how to do this and haven't been able to find anything.

These are my two arrays of lists. Both only have two lists in them.

```
        List<double>[] selection = new List<double>[selectionSize];
        List<double>[] crossover = new List<double>[2];
```

Each list in selection has 60 random numbers in it. What i'm trying to do is move half of those 60 random numbers from selection[0] and move them over to crossover [0].

I tried doing however i got and error.

```
crossover[0][i] = selection[0][i];
```

Please comment if you need me to provide more information.

Comment: That would just move over the entire list i only want to move over half of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like if you just want the second half of 60 elements

```
 crossover[0].AddRange(selection[0].Skip(30))
```

[List.AddRange(IEnumerable) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange?view=netframework-4.8)

> Adds the elements of the specified collection to the end of the
>   `List<T>`.

[Enumerable.Take(IEnumerable, Int32) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=netframework-4.8)

> Returns a specified number of contiguous elements from the start of a
>   sequence.

[Enumerable.Skip(IEnumerable, Int32) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip?view=netframework-4.8)

> Bypasses a specified number of elements in a sequence and then returns
>   the remaining elements.

Comment: This runs but then gives me this error which is the same error i had in the first place. System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: @OwenHodgson then your structures are not what you think they are, and something is null, i suggest double check how you are initializing your objects, also it might be worth while chucking a break point on and inspecting the runtime values

Comment: Fixed it thanks for the help. If i just wanted the second half how would i do that with this code?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way will be to use linq.

```
 crossover.AddRenge(selection.Take(selection.Count()/2));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq and more specifically, the Take & Skip method.

The Take() method extracts the first n elements (where n is a parameter to the method) from the beginning of the target sequence and returns a new sequence containing only the elements taken.

The Skip() method can be thought of as the exact opposite of the Take() method. Where the Take() method, returns a sequence containing the first n elements of the target sequence, the Skip() method "skips" over the first n elements in the sequence and returns a new sequence containing the remaining elements after the first n elements.

```
  crossover = selection.Take(2);
```

Gives you the first two

```
 crossover = selection.Skip(2);
```

Gives you everything after the first two.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you showed the full code that was causing the error, as well as the actual error message itself, but you can populate the lists like you were trying to do if you use two loops: one for each crossover item, and another for half the corresponding selection array's items (which is used to copy the items from `selection` to `crossover`). Then we need to call the `Add` method to add the items to the list, since the crossover list has no items yet (so we can't access them by index).

For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < crossover.Length; i++)
{
    // This may be what you were missing - we need to instantiate a new List first
    crossover[i] = new List<double>();

    for (int j = 0; j < selection[i].Count / 2; j++)
    {
        crossover[i].Add(selection[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is quite a lot of code so i didn't want it to get too confusing but this works as well what you have put.